# Build RCP doesn't start BundleException (EclipseBug?)

Tags: java, rcp, e4, java-11

I converted my RCP application from Java 8 to Java 11. From my Eclipse (latest version) everything works. My application can also be built.

Unfortunately, the problem is that the build of the RCP application can not be started.

> Error:
>       org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.e4.core.di.extensions.supplier [32]
>          Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.extender; filter: = "(& (osgi.extender = osgi.component) (version> = 1.3)
>   ((version> = 2.0))!)"

Unfortunately, I only found one entry of a current Eclipse bug [here](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=org.osgi.framework.BundleException%3A%20Could%20not%20resolve%20module%3A%20org.eclipse.e4.core.di.%20extensions.supplier%20%20%25%205B32%25%205D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Unresolved%20requirement%25%203A%20%20%20Require-Capability%25%203A%20%20%203B%20%20%20osgi.extender%25%20filter%25%203A%25%203D%25%2022%25%2028%25%2026%25%25%2028osgi.extender%203Dosgi.component%25%2029%25%2028version%25%203E%25%203D1.3%25%2029%25%2028%25%2021%25%203E%25%2028version%25%203D2.0%25%2029%25%2029%25%2029%25%2022).

How I can handle the bug?

Comment: Which version of Eclipse is your target platform? 2018-12 requires `org.apache.felix.scr` for this with revised start levels.

Comment: yes i use "2018-12". Thanks for this tip. The error is fixed but now the application do nothing. I didn't get any response when i start the application.exe.

Comment: I found an error in the logfile but i don't understand why it come now.
In Eclipse everything was fine and also with Java 8.
Why comes this error now, was anything changed in the meantime?
And the issue comes from my main Trimmed Window.

Comment: This is my error
!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2019-02-11 08:14:07.619
!MESSAGE Exception occurred while rendering: application.window.main=org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.basic.impl.TrimmedWindowImpl@1f14f20c ...
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: Could not find satisfiable constructor in org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.SelectionAggregator
 at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:420)
 at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:333)